# Postgres Procedure / function dependencies

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin tool, when I click on any user-defined function or a procedure on the left side panel, I'm able to see the dependent DB objects like user-defined `Types`, `Schema`, `Language`, `Roles` etc. in the '`Dependencies`' tab.

Is it possible to get the underlying query for those dependencies? Because I need to take the dependent objects for all the procedures and functions from a set of schemas.

Comment: Well, the source code is [freely available](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-source-code/). I guess you will have to go through the code to find the queries. But most certainly they will be using `pg_depend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code used in `pgAdmin` to show `Dependents` for PostgreSQL 12 plus versions.

This shows up all dependents for all objects. Needs to be filtered out for required objects using oid.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dep.classid, dep.objid, dep.objsubid, dep.refclassid, dep.refobjid,
                dep.deptype,
                cl.relkind, ad.adbin, pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) as adsrc,
    COALESCE(coc.relname, clrw.relname) AS ownertable,
    CASE WHEN cl.relname IS NOT NULL AND att.attname IS NOT NULL THEN cl.relname || COALESCE('.' || att.attname, '')
    ELSE COALESCE(cl.relname, co.conname, pr.proname, tg.tgname, ty.typname, la.lanname, rw.rulename, ns.nspname,
                  fs.srvname, fdw.fdwname, evt.evtname, col.collname, ftsc.cfgname, ftsd.dictname, ftsp.prsname,
                  ftst.tmplname, ext.extname, syn.synname, pl.polname)
    END AS refname,
    COALESCE(nsc.nspname, nso.nspname, nsp.nspname, nst.nspname, nsrw.nspname, colns.nspname, ftscns.nspname,
        ftsdns.nspname, ftspns.nspname, ftstns.nspname, synns.nspname) AS dep_obj_schema,
     CASE WHEN cl.relkind IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN cl.relkind = 'r' THEN cl.relkind || COALESCE(dep.objsubid::text, '') ELSE cl.relkind END
        WHEN tg.oid IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN tg.tgpackageoid != 0 THEN 'Tc'::text ELSE 'Tr'::text END
        WHEN ty.oid IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ty.typtype = 'd' THEN 'd'::text ELSE 'Ty'::text END
        WHEN ns.oid IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ns.nspparent != 0 AND ns.nspcompoundtrigger = false THEN 'Pa'::text ELSE 'n'::text END
        WHEN pr.oid IS NOT NULL AND (prtyp.typname = 'trigger' OR prtyp.typname = 'event_trigger') THEN 'Pt'::text
        WHEN pr.oid IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN pr.prokind = 'p' THEN 'Procedure'::text ELSE 'Function'::text END
        WHEN la.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'l'::text
        WHEN rw.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Rl'::text
        WHEN co.oid IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN co.contypid > 0 THEN 'Cd' ELSE 'C'::text || contype END
        WHEN ad.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'::text
        WHEN fs.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Fs'::text
        WHEN fdw.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Fw'::text
        WHEN evt.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Et'::text
        WHEN col.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Co'::text
        WHEN ftsc.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Fc'::text
        WHEN ftsp.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Fp'::text
        WHEN ftsd.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Fd'::text
        WHEN ftst.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ft'::text
        WHEN ext.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ex'::text
        WHEN syn.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Sy'::text
        WHEN pl.oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Rs'::text
    ELSE ''
    END AS dep_obj_type,
    CASE WHEN inhits.inhparent IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS is_inherits,
    CASE WHEN inhed.inhparent IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS is_inherited
FROM pg_catalog.pg_depend dep
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class cl ON dep.objid=cl.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON dep.objid=att.attrelid AND dep.objsubid=att.attnum
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsc ON cl.relnamespace=nsc.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc pr ON dep.objid=pr.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON pr.pronamespace=nsp.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_trigger tg ON dep.objid=tg.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ty ON dep.objid=ty.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nst ON ty.typnamespace=nst.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint co ON dep.objid=co.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class coc ON co.conrelid=coc.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nso ON co.connamespace=nso.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_rewrite rw ON dep.objid=rw.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class clrw ON clrw.oid=rw.ev_class
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsrw ON clrw.relnamespace=nsrw.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_language la ON dep.objid=la.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns ON dep.objid=ns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef ad ON ad.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server fs ON fs.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper fdw ON fdw.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type prtyp ON prtyp.oid = pr.prorettype
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_inherits inhits ON (inhits.inhrelid=dep.objid)
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_inherits inhed ON (inhed.inhparent=dep.objid)
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger evt ON evt.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_collation col ON col.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace colns ON col.collnamespace=colns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_config ftsc ON ftsc.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ftscns ON ftsc.cfgnamespace=ftscns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict ftsd ON ftsd.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ftsdns ON ftsd.dictnamespace=ftsdns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser ftsp ON ftsp.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ftspns ON ftsp.prsnamespace=ftspns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_ts_template ftst ON ftst.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ftstns ON ftst.tmplnamespace=ftstns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_extension ext ON ext.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_synonym syn ON syn.oid=dep.objid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace synns ON syn.synnamespace=synns.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_policy pl ON pl.oid=dep.objid
WHERE 
classid IN ( SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname IN
   ('pg_class', 'pg_constraint', 'pg_conversion', 'pg_language', 'pg_proc', 'pg_rewrite', 'pg_namespace',
   'pg_trigger', 'pg_type', 'pg_attrdef', 'pg_event_trigger', 'pg_foreign_server', 'pg_foreign_data_wrapper',
   'pg_collation', 'pg_ts_config', 'pg_ts_dict', 'pg_ts_parser', 'pg_ts_template', 'pg_extension',
   'pg_synonym', 'pg_policy'));
```